# Use of Semicolon in Obituary?

Tags: semicolons

Since the first two list items contain a comma, do I follow suit and use a semi-colon for the last two?

"He leaves behind his wife of 61 years,_____; children ____, ____, and ____; 9 grandchildren; and 2 great grandchildren."

Comment: Adding to the previous guidance, I’d normally be encouraging  someone to simply restructure complex lists like this into a more readable series of separate sentences. But in the formal context of an obituary what you propose does seem entirely reasonable.